# iterate through folder and pick specific file to copy to destination

Tags: batch-file

I have three folders inside a common folder in my source i.e.

```
Carname -> Data1
-> Datayyyymmdd
-> DataRPyyyymmdd
```

Need to take content from specific folder. something similar to LIKE command in java.

Comment: It's unclear for me what you are asking....

Comment: Edit your question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39895708/edit) and explain more your aim !

Answer (score 0):

Use `FOR`.

E.g. for files, use `FOR %%a IN (DataFile??) DO (echo %%a)` where DataFile?? is a pattern that matches your filenames. ? stands for a single character and * is a wilcard of any length.

For folders, use the /D switch. `FOR %%a IN (Carname\Data*) DO (echo %%a)` where Carname\Data* is a path and similar pattern for the folder.

You can nest them, e.g.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /d %%a IN ("Carname\Data*") DO (
    FOR %%b IN ("%%a\File*.txt") DO (
        ECHO %%b
    )
)
```